# left align text and icon in table header

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/t56xX/1/

notice how in the `<th>` that I have a border around you can see that everything is pushed right. I want it left.

It is also a requirement that the icon and the text don't wrap. This requirement is met, but cannot be broken when fixing the alignment.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

[image]

Notice the space I colored in red? It seems to me that the icon and label are aligned right, rather than left. How man I align the whole thing to the left? If there is space I want it on the right.

I know it seems kinda of trivial in this picture, but when you add data and look at it in my situation is looks odd that the headers are right aligned and the data is left aligned.

**Update 2:** Just to avoid further confusion, I want the icon on the left.

**Update 3:** simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/Lz4QY/1/ 
How would I get like 1px of "white space" on each side of the icon rather than lots of space on the left and none on the right?

Comment: Not able to interpret it correctly. Please elaborate your requirement/problem.

Comment: I also have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Looks like no one can understand you, try to re-word your question, read it over, see if you understand it then try again :)

Comment: sorry guys, i'll rephrase. I got caught up in something, sorry I didn't respond earlier.

Comment: alright, updated the question. Sorry for the terrible explanation the first time around...

Comment: Just a guess, but your icons may have a lot of space built in.  For example, the arrow all by itself might only be 6 pixels wide but the actual icon graphical image might be 16 pixels wide with 5 pixels of empty space on the right & left.   Then you'll have to open PhotoShop and crop them down or just create your own arrows from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
th {
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Remove the padding to the left and add whatever amount of padding (space) you want to the right of each th.

Comment: I think I identified the problem, not sure how to fix it. see the simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/Lz4QY/1/ Notice that changing the width removed "white" space from the right of the icon. I want to remove white space from the left of the icon. Is that even possible?

Comment: Now I understand... the problem is in the background image, you have to change the background position of that span containing the icon. Now it should be -128px 16px. Try to add to every th background-position:-132px -16px;

Comment: nice! -132 -16 with width of 7 works perfect! and actually I will likely use the 0 padding also, but thanks for the help positioning the icon!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem, maybe you want the icon to appear right of the boxes?

If this is the case, maybe you should give those  containing the icon a float:right property, instead of the left one they have now.

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/t56xX/5/.

```
th span span {
    float:right!important;
}
```

The !important is needed because as of now, the float:left property is inline in the s, so it won't get overwritten by the new one without using the important keyword.

Comment: That was my best guess, but then I thought "surely he's not asking a question where the solution is 'change `left` to `right`'". Then again, who knows? :)

Comment: I know, but I thought it could be the only possible thing related to "pushed left instead of right"! :P I'm really curious to see what he's meaning.

Comment: that's for trying to figure out what i meant, really appreciate it. However, that's not quite what I was looking for. I updated my question, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: however after viewing your solution, it seems that the icon itself might be taking up that extra room. The Jquery UI icons don't seem to have the best positioning... It seems the actual icon takes up more pixels than the actual little arrow things any way to shift the icon to the left?